# Can't delete the file with rm command

Tags: linux, rm

I have a file which can't deleted by rm.

```
/var/www/html/symfony4proj/var/cache/pool/+m7exph6c3/X/3/tCcgRMw5TEmYO-kHpJ0t
```

file satus

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 app app 2781 Jan  1  1970 tCcgRMw5TEmYO-kHpJ0t
```

Change permission before deleting.

```
[root@jp1 3]# chmod 0777 tCcgRMw5TEmYO-kHpJ0t`

-rwxrwxrwx 1 app app 2781 Jan  1  1970 tCcgRMw5TEmYO-kHpJ0t
```

then, try to delete

```
[root@jp1 3]# rm tCcgRMw5TEmYO-kHpJ0t`
rm: remove regular file `tCcgRMw5TEmYO-kHp0t'? y
```

It's not deleted and permission setting is return back to.

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 app app 2781 Jan  1  1970 tCcgRMw5TEmYO-kHpJ0t

[root@jp1 3]# which rm
alias rm='rm -i'
    /bin/rm
```

Is there any places I should check???

Comment: Check with `ls -i` if inode number changes after `rm`. Maybe something recreates the file.

Comment: `[root@jp1 3]# ls -i
9702169 tCcgRMw5TEmYO-kHpJ0t ` inode doesn't change before `rm` and after `rm`

Comment: Ah I tried to mv  `mv tCcgRMw5TEmYO-kHpJ0t test`. then There are two files like this `ls -i
9762374 tCcgRMw5TEmYO-kHpJ0t  9702169 test` Original file are mv to `test` then new file are created.